# Switching a relay with a 5V PWM circuit

Tags: transistors, pwm

I have a coil that has the following specs:

- Coil Resistance: 123 ohms
- Coil Current: 97.5 mA
- Switching Voltage: 14 VDC

I am trying to use a 5V PWM output from an ECU to switch the relay. I know I need to use a transistor but I am way over my head in regards to how to decide the part and design the ciruit.

Comment: You want to switch it at the PWM frequency, or at what point in the duty cycle? What is the on-level and off-level?

Comment: Take a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/146499/relays-flyback-diode-is-it-necessary

Comment: As soon as I receive any PWM signal. 0 for off, everything else is on. So I think I found a schematic of the circuit I need, just need to know if this makes sense:

http://www.supramania.com/photobucket/post-1847585-1-8c7b18af.jpg

Comment: I assume you want the relay to switch when the PWM duty cycle goes above or below a certain duty cycle? Not that you want to actually switch the relay directly with the PWM? Because relays can't switch that fast.

Comment: @SideSwipePB Yeah, that circuit should work. There will be a delay between when the PWM starts and when the relay activates, and especially when the signal tops and the relay deactivates. Take mind of potential overheating of the MOSFET as it switches on or off since it may do so very slowly producing heat in the process. It depends how slow and how frequently you do it.

Comment: @DKNguyen do you mean when the MOSFET switches on or off to trigger the relay? This will be triggering a fuel pump. So it will turn on at the start of the car and stay on until the car stops. Is this the best way to achieve a 14 discrete signal from a 5v PWM?

Comment: @SideSwipePB Yes, the MOSFET switches the current to the relay coil. I wouldn't say the best way, but it certainly is the simplest and should be effective. Turning on and off with the car is pretty infrequent so that should  minimize the heating from slow turning on and off.

Comment: @SideSwipePB Do you understand how it is supposed to work?